# How "up" came to mean "state of being complete"?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, history

as an example of my question there is "time is up". I wonder what is the path to a preposition that means "to a higher position" to mean: "state of being complete"
is there a history behind it? any relation with the word "up" with some event?

and the reason I ask this question is to help me to better undestand how to think in English

Comment: I'm thinking of a building being built, where when it's complete, it's fully "up"

Comment: When I think of "time's up", I think of the clock hand arriving at 12, pointing up.

Comment: prepositions are these tiny little building blocks of sentences and they often have dozens of meanings. Dictionary.com has 66 entries for "up". These functional-type words often get repurposed to all sorts of grammatical uses.

Comment: @Sam, I get this. My thoughts are more directed to how these meaning are formed get it? gotube and Esther gave me a glimpse of how. I believe those meaning aren't formed just by chance right? So I like to wonder the processes of them being formed get it?

Comment: @all, playoff and runoff are example of expression I can't visualize how they were formed

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this is not a question for English *learners* particularly.  It may get a good reception on [English.se]   Many, perhaps most question of etymology are incidental to learning English.  They are equally applicable to all users of English.  So [english.se] is a much better place to ask this question.

Comment: Does it specifically mean complete rather than over or (per Merriam-Webster) [at an end](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up)? There are a lot of expressions like give up, burn up, use up, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this is not a question for English learners particularly. It may get a good reception on English Language & Usage Many, perhaps most question of etymology are incidental to learning English. They are equally applicable to all users of English. So English Language & Usage is a much better place to ask this question

Answer (score 1):

There are proposals in the Conceptual Metaphor Theory literature for how spatial terms acquire more abstract meanings. According to Grady's "primary metaphor" theory, basic childhood experiences in the world are likely to give rise to metaphors. It seems plausible that the meaning of "filling up" (a container, e.g. with liquid) is motivated by the rising of the liquid, and also involves completion. So that may have been the basis for generalizing to other completion meanings.

Comment: this is very revealing. Thanks. do you have anything on how playoff was formed?

Comment: Not sure but it may be related to "face off". https://www.etymonline.com/word/face-off